# The permission of SystemProperties.set()?

Tags: android

I was developing an app on Android L,and I needed to use       `SystemProperties.set()`
The key `"persist.sys.xxx`" needed to be set but was not defined.

Then `AndroidRutimeException` occurred.So I thought it may be permission issue.
So Is the method `SystemProperties.set()` need `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` ?

Comment: Did you try this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

Comment: Yes,I've added the permission.